# Some entries in the suggested edit stats view don't render next to the user image

Tags: bug, design, suggested-edit-stats

As you can see in the below screen shot, some entries in the [suggested edit stats view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits) don't render next to the user image.

> [image: misalignment]

Can this be fixed please?